# D3: Multiple Values on Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a graph I need to make but having a hard time figuring out the best approach. Essentially what I need is two different data sets on the y-axis that are separate values but still related. At zero on the y-axis the data set changes to a different value that goes in positive increments.[This is an example of the type of graph I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFACM.png)

What would be the best way to go about creating this? While I can certainly find examples of multiple y-axis graphs, they don't seem to account for this use case.

Comment: Basically have 2 separate charts in the same `g` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed create two different scales, which is probably the *standard* solution, or... you can create only one scale! So, just for the sake of curiosity, here is how to do it:

Create a scale going from `-10` to `10`...

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-10, 10])
```

... changing the negative values to positive ones in the axis...

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickFormat(d => d < 0 ? Math.abs(d) : d);
```

... and, of course, changing the `y` values to negative ones in the data for the lines below the x axis (here named `dataInspiration`):

```
dataInspiration.forEach(d => d.y = -d.y)
```

Here is a demo using random numbers:

```js
var width = 600,
  height = 200,
  padding = 20;

svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var dataExpiration = d3.range(10).map(d => ({
  x: d,
  y: Math.random() * 10
}));
var dataInspiration = d3.range(10).map(d => ({
  x: d,
  y: Math.random() * 10
}));

dataInspiration.forEach(d => d.y = -d.y)

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(d3.range(10))
  .range([padding, width - padding]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-10, 10])
  .range([height - padding, padding])

var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y(d => yScale(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var lineExpiration = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("d", line(dataExpiration));

var lineInspiration = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", line(dataInspiration));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d => d != 0 ? d : null);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickFormat(d => d < 0 ? Math.abs(d) : d);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + yScale(0) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```